# What is the argument selector tracking a defined score (not [score_min=])?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

What if I want to make a command like this:

```
execute @e[score_A=10] ~ ~ ~ summon Creeper
```

So that the entity must have a score of 10 (not less, not more)?

Does it even exist that or a `[score_A_max=]` argument?

I know about scoreboard players test, but i guess it is not the case to use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `score_NAME` parameter is the maximum score while `score_NAME_min` is the minimum score. You can combine them for an exact value:

```
/execute @a[score_A_min=10,score_A=10] ~ ~ ~ summon Creeper
```