# Command blocks executing w/out required parameters met

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to use command blocks to spawn a Grinder mob **once** at a certain spot whenever the player's "Grinders" score is equal to the set ammount. Eg. 1.
I'm using this command (With differences for each amount and position):

execute @p[score_Grinders=20] ~ ~ ~ setblock 17 5 22 redstone_block

The setblock sets a block of redstone above a set of command blocks that spawn the Grinder, and **those** work. However, even when the Grinders score is not met, it places the block, and I can't delete it without first disabling the command block. When inspecting the command block it says it can't execute the command as the player. Please help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the argument selector tracking a defined score (not \[score\_min=\])?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/241801/what-is-the-argument-selector-tracking-a-defined-score-not-score-min)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`score_NAME` is the *maximum* score, not exact score (so 20 or lower), while `score_NAME_min` is minimum. If you want an exact score, you must include both minimum and maximum:

```
/execute @p[score_Grinders_min=20,score_Grinders=20] ~ ~ ~ setblock 17 5 22 redstone_block
```