# Detecting an exact score

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So let's say I have a score of 4 out of 5. How can I use `/testfor` to detect I have 4 points. I know how to use `/testfor @p[score_Points_min=5`. If I take out the `min` I get this: `/testfor @p[score_Points=4]` You know, to detect that I have 4 points. This should work right? No, it still activates when I have 2 points. I want this to tell me I have 4 points. I've tried every single command that would possibly work. However it STILL consists of activating no matter what score I have. How can I get this to work? For any more info ask me!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Command blocks executing w/out required parameters met](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/245832/command-blocks-executing-w-out-required-parameters-met)

Comment: @pppery That question is planned to be closed as dupe of [What is the argument selector tracking a defined score (not [score_min=])?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/241801/250180), so voting to close as dupe of that instead.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 Yes, sorry, I didn't realize that question was a duplicate until I had already flagged this one.

Answer (score 1):

The two arguments to test a scoreboard objective are `score_name` and `score_name_min`. The first detects anyone with that score or below, and the latter detects anyone with that score or above.

It works in this slightly confusing way because `r` (the radius argument, which was introduced first) made intuitive sense to be "within this radius", and `rm` to be the minimum radius (at least this far away). This was continued on into the other arguments where it doesn't make as much sense.

To detect for an exact score, you need to use both of these arguments:

```
/testfor @p[score_Points=4,score_Points_min=4]
```

Comment: @Emeraldimension No problem; press the tick next to the answer if it answered your question.