# What is the command to give a player a diamond helmet if they have a specific scoreboard score?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am making a map and I want to be able to give points to players, which I have down (using the scoreboard command). But I want to be able to see if a player has a specific score and reward them with a diamond helmet.

---

Also, I want to replace the item on their head with the diamond cap, not just use /give to give it to them. If you can give me the command or set of commands that would be great! I'm using 1.9.2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the argument selector tracking a defined score (not \[score\_min=\])?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/241801/what-is-the-argument-selector-tracking-a-defined-score-not-score-min)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/give @a[score_name_min=1] minecraft:diamond_helmet
```

is the command to give everyone with a minimum score of 1 in 'name' a diamond helmet. Just replace the objective 'name' with your own name.

```
/give @a[score_name_min=1,score_name=1] minecraft:diamond_helmet
```

is the command to give everyone with an exact score of 1 in 'name' a diamond helmet. Just replace the objective 'name' with your own name.

As for replacing inventory items; I do know a way for 1.9.2, but for 1.8:

```
/give @a[score_name_min=1] {Inventory:[{Slot:103b,id:"minecraft:diamond_helmet"}]}
```

would give it in slot 103b (I believe this is the helmet slot, but I am not sure.)

Comment: `/give` cannot place in specific slots. The `/replaceitem` command does that.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to modify the command to replace the helmet with @Skylinerw's help.

Comment: 1.13 syntax: `@a[scores={name=1..}]`